# Ayuda a hacer que mi código en C# sea un poco mas corto y efectivo

Tags: c#, revisión-de-código

Hola necesito una ayuda por favor, quisiera que me ayudaran a hacer que mi código sea un poco mas corto y efectivo! Agradecería sus repuestas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string confirmacion;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                menu();
                Console.Write("\nIntroduzca la opcion: ");
                int opcion = Validacionint();
                    switch (opcion)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("1. Invertir Numero");
                            invertir();

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("2. Factorial");
                            int x;
                            Console.Write("Ingrese un Numero: "); x = Validacionint();
                            Console.Write("El factorial de  " + x + " es: " + Factorial(x));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("3. Fibonacci");
                            int y;
                            Console.Write("Ingrese un Numero: "); y = Validacionint();
                            Console.Write("El numero en la Posicion " + y + " de la sucesion Fibonacci es: " + fibo(y));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Environment.Exit(-1);
                            break;
                    }
                Console.Write("\nDesea Repetir la Operacion: ");
                confirmacion = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (confirmacion == "SI" || confirmacion == "si");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        static void menu()
        {

            Console.Write("1. Invertir un Numero" + Environment.NewLine + "2. Factorial" + Environment.NewLine + "3. Fibonacci" + Environment.NewLine + "4. Salir");

        }

        static void invertir()
        {
            string num;
            double numero;
            Console.Write("Ingrese un Numeron: "); numero = Validaciondouble();
            num = numero.ToString();
            char[] invertir = num.ToArray();
            char[] sec = invertir.Reverse().ToArray();
            string cad = new string(sec);
            Console.Write("El Numero Invertido es: " + Convert.ToDouble(cad));
        }
        static int Factorial(int numero)
        {
            if (numero == 0) return 1;
            else
            {
                return numero * Factorial(numero - 1);
            }

        }
        static int fibo(int numero)
        {
            if (numero < 2) return 1;
            else
            {
                return fibo(numero - 2) + fibo(numero - 1);
            }
        }
        static int Validacionint()
        {
            int x = 0;
            bool conversion = false;
            while (!conversion)
            {
                conversion = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
                if (!conversion) Console.Write("Valor no Valido Ingrese Nuevamente un Numero: ");
            }
            return x;

        }
        static double Validaciondouble()
        {
            double x = 0;
            bool conversion = false;
            while (!conversion)
            {
                conversion = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
                if (!conversion) Console.Write("Valor no Valido Ingrese Nuevamente un Numero: ");
            }
            return x;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto mis recomendaciones para hacer más legible y corto tu código:

1. Usa el operador condicional y  Expression Bodied Functions

   ```
   static int Factorial(int n) => n == 0 ? 1 : n * Factorial(n - 1);

   static int Fibonacci(int n) => n < 2 ? 1 :Fibonacci(n-2) +Fibonacci(n-1);
   ```
2. Quita los enunciados `using` que no necesitas. Solo estas utilizando:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   ```
3. Usa cadenas interpoladas por ejemplo:

   ```
   Console.Write($"El número...{y} de la sucesión de Fibonacci es:{fibo(y)}");
   ```
4. En la opción 4 considero que no deberías  mandar el código de salida -1, esto debido a que se esta ejecutando una opción permitida y el programa no presento errores en su ejecución. puedes cambiarla por`Environment.Exit(0);`. o todavía mejor la podrías omitir por completo.
5. Separa responsabilidades. El método `Validacionint` solicita ,procesa y muestra los datos al usuario . Seria mejor que tuviera  un parámetro  tipo int y regresara un string. Esto para tratar de lo pueda reutilizar en alguna otra aplicación. Como esta seria imposible utilizarlo en una aplicacion con GUI.
   Puedes crear una clase estática con tus métodos `fibo` y `Factorial` y reutilizarlos en otros proyectos.
6. Sigue las convenciones al escribir código. Nombra los iniciando con mayúscula
   [C# Code Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)
7. mejora el menú. Cuando esperas un entero informase lo al usuario. Ponle un título. No limpies la consola a mi me gusta revisar el histórico de comandos. Mejora la ortografía.
8. Trata de implementar el método `invertir` sin usar los métodos de extensión `Reverse().ToArray()`;de espacio de nombres `System.Linq`